# Crear una cadena con un shell script y luego ejecutarlo desde C

Tags: c, bash, shell, seguridad

Quiero poder leer un archivo como cadena de texto, y luego ejecutar esa cadena de texto como un script de shell.

Quiero hacer en C algo del estilo (esquematizo):

```
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* file = argv[1];
    char* file_string = file_to_string(file);
    execv("/bin/bash", file_to_string)
    return 0;  
}
...
```

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* file = argv[1];
    char* arguments[] = { "bash", file, NULL };

    printf("Opening file: %s\n", file);

    execv("/bin/bash", arguments);

    return 0;
}
```

Y funciona bien:

```
$ gcc bash2exe.c -o bash2exe && ./bash2exe script.sh
Opening file: script.sh
hola mundo
2
```

Pero no quiero ejecutar un archivo. Quiero poder tener el payload y luego poder ejecutarlo.

Casi como si leyera el contenido y lo "pipeara" a un interprete de bash.

### Update 1

Por el momento logré conseguir algo parecido utilizando esto:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int err;
  size_t f_size;
  char* f_data;
  char* file = argv[1];

  f_data = c_read_file(file, &err, &f_size);

  system(f_data);

  return 0;
}
```

Que lee el script, almacena el contenido en un buffer, y luego el buffer es pasado a `system()`.

Al correr tengo:

```
$ gcc read_and_execute.c -o read_and_execute && ./read_and_execute script.sh
hola mundo
2
```

Esto es lo que llevo hecho: https://gitlab.com/mrc_es/bash2exe/-/blob/development/read_and_execute.c

Comment: ... Lo que buscas es solo leer un archivo: https://medium.com/10-goto-10/manejo-de-archivos-en-c-19f85b31ddd    y ejecutar lo leido previamente.

Comment: Exacto. Justo eso quiero.